# Cannot link gosseract v2.2.1 on masOS: ld: library 'lept' not found

Tags: c++, macos, go, clang, gosseract

I have installed `tesseract 5.3.4` and `leptonica 1.84.1` from `homebrew`.
When I'm trying to run even the simplest code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/otiai10/gosseract"
)

func main() {

    client := gosseract.NewClient()
    _ = client

}
```

I get the following error:

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link:
>
> running c++ failed: exit status 1
>
> ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-llept', '-ltesseract'
>
> ld: library 'lept' not found
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)

I've searched through all `cmake` files related to `tesseract` and  `leptonica` and couldn't find linker options like `-llept`.
Also `leptonica` brings shared libraries like `libleptonica.6.dylib` not `liblept.6.dylib`, but even making corresponding symlinks doesn't help.

Is there any something else I'm missing which is required to make `gosseract` work on `masOS Sonoma` with `go1.22`?

Comment: Have you checked the [tessaract-doc](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/Compiling.md#macos-with-homebrew) referenced in the readme of the `gosseract` where it gives tutorial how to compile and install the tessaract into your system.

Comment: @BerkantAy, I have. The instruction for masOS is quite outdated, however i tried it. 
Still it doesn't work. I tried also with `gcc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `github.com/otiai10/gosseract/client.go` from:

```
// #if __FreeBSD__ >= 10
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -llept -ltesseract
// #else
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++0x
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -llept
// #endif
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <stdbool.h>
// #include "tessbridge.h"
```

to:

```
// #if __FreeBSD__ >= 10
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lleptonica -ltesseract
// #else
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++0x
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lleptonica
// #endif
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <stdbool.h>
// #include "tessbridge.h"
```

Did the trick. The problem here is if you choose to do  so as well, you'll have to vendor this module  in your application and support your version yourself.

As I mentioned in my question, I installed `tesseract` and `leptonica` using `homebrew`. It doesn't touch anything in `/usr/local`.
I made a symlink  `/usr/local/lib -> /opt/homebrew/lib` in order not to edit `gosseract` itself further, so this may be not a very good solution.

UPDATE:

In `github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2` (latest version as of 2024-03-06 is 2.4.1) has the `-llept` issue sort of fixed, however it is still necessary to synmlink  `/usr/local/lib` to `/opt/homebrew/lib`